# Turn Off Anti-aliasing in Outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, internet-explorer-9, anti-aliasing

I am running Outlook 2003 in Windows 7x64 with Internet Explorer 9. When I read a mail in the Reading Pane or by opening it, the text is anti-aliased.

When I reply to a message, the text is not anti-aliased.

How do I turn off anti-aliasing for viewing messages in Outlook?

(Microsoft's name for anti-aliasing is Cleartype, in case anyone is searching on that term.)

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2003 uses Internet Explorer to render the emails. Internet Explorer 9 always uses ClearType and does not have an option to turn it off. Internet Explorer 8 and previous allow you to turn off ClearType.

Uninstall Internet Explorer 9. This should leave you with Internet Explorer 8 or earlier.

Open Internet Explorer and go to Tools->Options. Select the Advanced tab. Under "Multimedia", make sure that "Always use ClearType for HTML" is not checked.